# Connection failure in TCP/IP socket C program used in 88 threads

Tags: multithreading, sockets, pthreads, tcp

I am using this below mentioned TCP IP socket code to transfer data between 88 threads of client and server machine.

Each thread is assigned to a different core. Yes, It is an 88 core machine.

Each socket is creating a socket and performing send or receive operation.

Each socket assigned to a different port number. (Port number starting from 8020 to 8108)

The below mentioned code is used in each of server and client code thread respectively.

The issue here is, For few executions, in some sockets or threads,  data received at client is matching with data sent by server.

However in some executions, the data is not matching in few sockets out of 100.  say i am finding, for around 50 sockets/threads data buffer are matching but rest, they do not.

Those which are not matching,  sometimes post an error saying "connection reset by peer" or "connection failed", then return from the function.

Why is this error occurring randomly for few sockets and in few executions only?

This sample program implemented for a single thread works fine. The issue is occurring in multi-threaded environment when 88 threads are running.

Tried few troubleshooting steps:

1. Changing port number range.
2. Verified in sytem monitor that data rate is around 117 MB/s so included usleep to bring down the data rate.
3. Verified that there are no errors when "send" operation is performed in server code. Data read failure occurs only in the client code.

The sample code is available at the link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/

We have used the same API's but for 88 threads instead of 1 thread.

Comment: This code is being run in l_ubuntu 1604 OS and compiler used is gcc

Comment: 88 cores, 1 network interface? You'd be having to do some pretty heavy weight processing before 88 cores were needed to chew on data flowing through a single network interface. That example code doesn't guarantee to read whole messages: https://linux.die.net/man/3/read